# how do I pass cert, key and ca to sqlalchemy url in alembic?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

how do I pass cert, key and ca to sqlalchemy url in alembic?

Can we modify anything in `env.py`?

can we pass ssl args in

```py
context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
        template_args={'ssl': ssl_args},
    )
```

something like this?